# External HDD not properly recognized

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, external-disk, ntfs

Today I connected my external HDD (WD elements) to my MBP and it was not recognised properly. The disk has two partitions, one an NTFS partition with some files and the other a Veracrypt partition.
Normally when I connect the drive it will automatically mount the NTFS partition and I can manually mount the other partition through Veracrypt. However when I now connect the drive it does not do anything. When I look in the Disk Utility it only shows the drive but no volumes:

[image: Disk Utility screenshot]

When I execute `diskutil list` I get the following result:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         500.0 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +500.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            456.8 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 21.8 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                518.1 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4

/dev/disk3 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *5.0 TB     disk3
   1:         Microsoft Reserved                         134.2 MB   disk3s1
   2:       Microsoft Basic Data                         429.9 GB   disk3s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data                         4.6 TB     disk3s3
```

So it seems it does recognise the partitions. When I try to mount the NTFS partition (disk3s2) it returns 'Volume on disk3s2 timed out waiting to mount'. When I try to do first aid on the drive in the Disk Utility application I get the error 'Failed to eject "WD Elements 107C Media" because it is currently in use.

When I run first aid it also does not do anything useful:
[image: First Aid output]

Anyone got any tips for how to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you have a chance to test whether Windows can mount the NTFS partition?

Comment: For futher reference: I had one situation where two external HDD couldn't be recognized. I messed up one before I restarted the macbook and afterwards the other one was recognized once more. So a restart is worth a try.